# How to design an interactive service in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my android app I am updating contents in a 2-step process:

1. The first step is to download a JSON document containing the data model. The JSON document also comprises a list of media files for different languages, e.g. german videos, english videos etc.
2. In the second step the media files for a specific language are downloaded, e.g. only the german videos. The user should be able to select which language should be downloaded. However, the available languages are only known after step one, so the user has to be prompted.

I think it makes sense to design the 2-step download as one service. If doing so, how can the service interactively ask the user which language should be downloaded, e.g. by presenting an `AlertDialog`?

Comment: the service cannot present anything by itself, it does not have a UI. You need to callback to the Activity when the first step is complete and tell the service what the user chose

Answer (score 0):

The service can present a UI element by sending a broadcast to an Activity or Fragment.

Using BroadcastReceivers inside your Activity/Fragment you can listen for actions from a service. You can then restart the service with different conditions passed through the service's intent.